# Using QuickCheck to generate multiple arbitrary parameters for a given function

Tags: haskell, typeclass, quickcheck

**Context**

I have the following function:

```
prop_SignAndVerify :: (PrivKey a b) => Blind a -> BS.ByteString -> Bool
prop_SignAndVerify bsk msg = case verify pk msg sig of
                             Left e -> error e
                             Right b -> b
  where
    sk  = getBlind bsk
    pk  = toPublic sk
    sig = case sign sk msg of
               Left e -> error e
               Right s -> s
```

I would like to do something like:

```
-- instance PrivKey RSA.PrivateKey RSA.PublicKey where...
genRSA :: Gen RSA.PrivateKey
genRSAMessage :: Gen BS.ByteString

main = do
  quickCheck . verbose 
  $ forAll genRSA 
  $ forAll genRSAMessage prop_SignAndVerify
```

That is, I would like to use explicit generators to generate arbitrary values for `Blind a` and `BS.ByteString` in the parameters of `prop_SignAndVerify`.

The code above, however, doesn't work, because the function `forAll` has type signature:

```
forAll :: (Show a, Testable prop) => Gen a -> (a -> prop) -> Property
```

This function runs the generator and apples the generated arbitrary value to `(a -> prop)`, returning a `Property`. This `Property` however cannot be further partially applied; it hides the underlying function.

I think what we need for the above to work would be something like:

```
forAll' :: (Show a,  Testable prop) => Gen a -> (a -> prop) -> prop
```

**Question**

So my question is, how can I use `genRSA` and `genRSAMessage` over the parameters of `prop_SignAndVerify`, or is there an alternative approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of the monadic nature of `Gen` to compose a more complex `Gen` value from your property:

```
main =
  let g = do
            key <- genRSA
            message <- genRSAMessage
            return $ prop_SignAndVerify (Blind key) message
  in quickCheck . verbose $ forAll g id
```

Here, `g` is a `Gen Bool` value.

Alternatively, you can take advantage of the applicative nature of `Gen` and compose `g` using `<*>`:

```
main =
  let g =
        return (\key message -> prop_SignAndVerify (Blind key) message)
        <*> genRSA
        <*> genRSAMessage
  in quickCheck . verbose $ forAll g id
```

`g` is still a `Gen Bool` value here as well.

Comment: I would just avoid the return in the applicative version (note the <$> instead of first <*>):  (\key message -> prop_SignAndVerify (Blind key) message)
        <$> genRSA
        <*> genRSAMessage

Answer (score 9):

You want to check `prop_SignAndVerify key message` for <s>all</s> many `key`s and `message`s. So if we had a fixed `key`, our tests would look like that:

```
main = do
  quickCheck . verbose $ 
    let key = someGeneratedKey
    in forAll genRSAMessage $ \message ->
         prop_SignAndVerify key message
```

If we had a fixed `message`, our test would look like this:

```
main = do
  quickCheck . verbose $ 
    forAll genRSAMessage $ \key ->
      let message = someMessage
      in prop_SignAndVerify key message
```

All we have to do is to combine both variants:

```
main = do
  quickCheck . verbose $ 
    forAll genRSA        $ \key ->
    forAll genRSAMessage $ \message ->
      prop_SignAndVerify key message
```

You can get rid of the `message` due to eta conversion, but in my opinion tests should be easily readable.

Comment: After double eta conversion: `quickCheck . verbose $ forAll genRSA $ forAll genRSAMessage . prop_SignAndVerify` I find it nice and readable, but of course it's a matter of taste.