# How to iteratively test in Haskell using QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, testing, quickcheck

How do you generate a random instance in Haskell QuickCheck and then run further tests on this very instance?

Let me demonstrate by giving an example. Within the following code snippet I generate an `Int` and then want to run further tests on this very `Int`:

```
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}

import           Test.Tasty
import           Test.Tasty.QuickCheck as QC
import qualified Debug.Trace as Trace

main :: IO()
main = defaultMain tests

test1 :: Int -> Property
test1 i = withMaxSuccess 2 (test2 i)

test2 :: Int -> (Int, Int) -> Property
test2 i (a, b) =
  Trace.trace ("(n,a,b) = " ++ show (i, a, b)) $
  property True

tests :: TestTree
tests =
  testGroup
  "Test suite"
  [
    QC.testProperty "Test" (withMaxSuccess 3 test1)
  ]
```

As output I want to have something like:

```
(n,a,b) = (0,0,0)
(n,a,b) = (0,1,2)
(n,a,b) = (-1,-1,-1)
(n,a,b) = (-1,-2,-3)
(n,a,b) = (2,0,-2)
(n,a,b) = (2,1,-1)
```

But instead I get:

```
(n,a,b) = (0,0,0)
(n,a,b) = (-1,-1,-1)
(n,a,b) = (2,0,-2)
```

I found this [post (How can QuickCheck test all properties for each sample)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233443/how-can-quickcheck-test-all-properties-for-each-sample), but it didn't really help me.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the `withMaxSuccess` function:

```
withMaxSuccess :: Testable prop => Int -> prop -> Property
```

This is a function that takes any `Testable` and turns it into a `Property`. The resulting `Property` has the behaviour that it'll run for a maximum number as specified by the `Int`.

The `test1` function is a `Testable` instance. When you call `withMaxSuccess 3 test1` you change the behaviour of `test1`, so that *when it runs* it runs for a maximum of three times.

While `test1` returns a `Property` with the behaviour that it runs only two times (`withMaxSuccess 2`), it gets overridden by `withMaxSuccess 3`.

The `withMaxSuccess` function doesn't run the test, it just changes the definition of a property. `withMaxSuccess 3` is the latest modification of the property, so that's why you see it running three times.

Comment: Best answer until now ;) Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for, that is to reuse the Int generated for test1 in test2 a given number of times?

Comment: @JohnSmith Does something like this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45541161/126014 I'm a little pressed for time right now, but I'll be happy to help later today, if required.

Comment: I am trying to work my way through the code snippet in the link. I will update here on my progress tomorrow. Thanks.